# Avoiding to build specific files when building the kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, ubuntu-14.04

I was wondering if I can set up a parameter in the kernel config file to avoid building some files. For example, after building the kernel with the command:

```
make -j6 deb-pkg
```

it generates the following files:

```
_amd64.changes
.debian.tar.gz
.dsc
.orig.tar.gz
```

So my question here is: how can I avoid generating these files after compiling the kernel?

I know that there are some parameters in the kernel config file for this.

Comment: How is it supposed to build the .deb without the files the .deb is made of?

Comment: sorry for the missed information, and yes, i have the deb packages as well :)

Comment: These files are generated as a part of the package build process. They have to be created.